# Terminating ThreadPool-Threads hanging in swt syncExec

Tags: java, concurrency, swt, threadpool, terminate

When disposing the display the threadpool threads always hang in the swt syncExec call. How can I avoid this situation and cleanly shutdown the threads? Calling shutdownNow inside the shell disposeListener do not work.

The following example shows the runnable which is executed by the threadpool thread. You can find the complete code here: http://www.java-forum.org/awt-swing-javafx-and-swt/164617-threadpool-sicher-beenden-verwendung-swt-widgets-display-syncexec.html

```
private class DoSomething implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      try { Thread.sleep( 500 ); } catch( InterruptedException e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
      if( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
        display.syncExec( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              drawshit( display );
            }
         });
      }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `syncExec()` calls in `DoSomething` are causing a dead lock. If you replace `syncExec()` with `asyncExec()` the thread pool is shut down just fine. Is there a specific reason why you use `syncExec()`?

Alternatively you should be able to run the shutdown code from a separate thread to avoid the problem.

Comment: Thank you!!! The thread pool performs some operations on the data picked up with the syncExec() call, therefore the thread pool have to wait for the result.